# When user presses "enter" key or space enter then error message pops up

Tags: java, user-input, is-empty

I would like to print an error message when the user presses enter or space enter instead of a string. I have tried isEquals("") and isEmpty() but haven't found anything that works yet.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class check{
    public static void main(String args[]){
      System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      String input = keyboard.next();

      if(input.equals("")){
        System.out.println("Empty");
      } else {
        System.out.println("number inputed");
    }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, change `keyboard.next()` to `keyboard.nextLine()`, use `trim()` to remove unnecessary spaces, check with `isEmpty()`.

```
String input = keyboard.nextLine().trim();
if (input.isEmpty()) {
    // error message
} else {
    // good to go
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class check{
    public static void main(String args[]){
      System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      String input = keyboard.nextLine();


      if(input.trim().equals("")){
        System.out.println("Empty");
      } else {
        System.out.println("number inputed");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check whether the string input is empty, you can use the `String.isEmpty()` method. Look below:

```
String input = keyboard.nextLine();
if(!input.isEmpty()) {
  //the input is not empty! 
} 
else {
  //the input is empty! 
}
```

Note, however, that since you want to receive numbers as inputs you should not retrieve them as strings. Below is an example where the program retrieves a `double` from the user. [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) provides many methods to validate the user's input. In this case, I'm using `hasNextDouble()` to check whether the input is a number.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Enter a number:");

while(!scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
  System.out.println("That's not a number!");
  scanner.next();
} 

double numberInput = scanner.nextDouble();
System.out.println("The entered number was " + numberInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, I don't get an error when running your code. However, I noticed that your code simply doesn't react to an empty input (just pressing enter). If you want to check for that, you can use keyboard.nextLine().

Judging by the rest of your code, it seems like you want the user to input only a number. An easy way to check if the user entered an integer if you're using Scanner is keyboard.hasNextInt().

Meaning you can do something like this:

```
if(keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
  int yourNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Your number is: " + your Number);
}
else {
  System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample program similar to yours and used nextLine() instead of next(). When user enters space and clicks enter he will print "space" else "a number".

[image]